# Rename ':2f' to '-' on folder names in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, regex

I've got a hard drive taken from a NAS drive where files had been put on from a Mac - However, some of the filenames had been, for example, 'backup 16/07/14' which has then been changed to 'backup 16:2f07:2f14' on the NAS.

This is proving an issue when copying files over to a new NAS. So what i'm looking to do is just switch the ':2f' to '-' by running a command on a folder that houses all these other folders.

I'm reasonably new to Linux, so i'm stuck. I've loaded up the hard drive on ubuntu on a virtual machine.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you have `perl-rename` aka `prename`:

```
find . -depth -name "*:*" -exec perl-rename 's/:2f/-/g' {} +
```

Without:

```
find . -depth -name "*:*" |
while read -r name; do
    mv -nT "$name" "${name//:2f/-}"
fi
```

Comment: Might want a `-print0` and `-d ''` there just for safety.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use

```
sed
```

command. It can be used to **replace** characters in filenames. You first find files with

```
find
```

command and use "|" to pipe them to sed.

Comment: I tried running `find . -type f | xargs sed -i " 's/:2f/-/g'` But it doesn't seem to run?

Comment: Also, it's directory names if that makes a difference?

Comment: @Peter: It does run; it just doesn't do what you both are expecting. The main tool here, `sed -i`, **does not _rename_ files; it _edits_ files.** You're asking it to apply the regex to the files' _contents_. To rename, you need a different tool, e.g. `perl-rename`. /// And yes, directory names do make a difference: you added `-type f`, so you're asking for a list of files specifically, not directories. To list all directories, it would be `-type d`.