# Using xargs with $() - operator precedence?

Tags: linux, bash, xargs

Inspired by [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/783793/rename-2f-to-on-folder-names-in-linux).  The original question, in short, is "How to turn all `:2f` into `-` in all files within a folder".  e.g. If I have a file `./abc:2fdef` it should be renamed into `./abc-def`.

At first I thought it to be a simple task... `find` all files and then `sed` to replace `:2f` into `-`.  When trying to construct a one-liner, I come up with the command:

```
find . -type f -name '*:2f*' | xargs -I {} mv {} $(echo {} | sed "s/:2f/-/ig")
```

However it doesn't work.  After doing lots of testing, I found that the problem lays at the `xargs` part - $() was executed before `xargs` place substitute `{}` with the file names.  To elaborate,

```
xargs -I {} mv {} $(echo {} | sed "s/:2f/-/ig")
```

was evaluated as (`$(...)` was evaluated)

```
xargs -I {} mv {} {}
```

and then

```
mv ./abc:2fdef ./abc:2fdef
```

Which was not that I am expecting.  So, my question is, can I make xargs substitute all `{}` into filenames before evaluating the `$(...)` part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, because `xargs` can't substitute something before the shell calls `xargs` with `$(…)` already evaluated. This is due to the order of [shell expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html).

I would probably do it like so:

```
find . -type f -name '*:2f*' -exec bash -c 'mv -- "$0" "${0//:2f/-}"' {} \;
```

Here, the shell call is evaluated from every file found by `find`, and the string replacement is done [with shell features](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) rather than another call to `sed`.

Also, this approach is safer because spaces in filenames are properly handled (through double-quoting the arguments to the `mv` call). More about that [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments).

---

For these tasks you probably want a more efficient tool like [`zmv`](http://zshwiki.org/home/builtin/functions/zmv), which is available in Zsh, or the Perl `rename`, which is bundled with many Linux distributions:

```
rename 's/:2f/-/' *
```

Comment: +1 for "order of shell expansion" and "string replacement as shell features".  Thanks!